# xmodmap resets when keyboard mode changes

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I have a Keychron K2 mechanical keyboard and the keys on the righthand side of the keyboard look like this:

[image]

I would like to swap them to a more standard layout, so that, from top to bottom, I would have `Light Toggle`, `Home`, `Page Up`, `Page Down`, and `End`.

I used `xev` to retrieve the key codes and wrote a small script that uses `xmodmap` to swap them to my liking:

```
#!/bin/bash

xmodmap -e "keycode 110 = Next" && xmodmap -e "keycode 112 = Home" && xmodmap -e "keycode 117 = Prior"
```

This script is executed on start up and works exactly as expected.

The problem is this keyboard is both wired and Bluetooth. When I switch between wired mode to Bluetooth mode or vice-versa, the keys go back to their default position and I need to manually run my script above one more time. `xev` shows to me that in both cases the key codes are the same. Is there a better way of tackling this so that these keys are swapped regardless of the keyboard mode I use?

Comment: Alternatively, is there a better way of accomplishing this? On Windows (I'm dual booting), I managed to hard code the changes directly in the registry, so that every keyboard will have those swapped. Is there an equivalent for Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Linux Mint (and Ubuntu derivates) `xmodmap` resets whenever a keyboard is plugged/unplugged or when a new keyboard is detected. In the case of keyboards with dual mode like mine, the system understands that these are two separate keyboards and will reset `xmodmap` at that point.

The solution to this is to edit the file `pc` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` using:

```
$ sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

Then change lines 77, 78, and 81 from...:

```
    key <HOME> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Prior        ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Next         ]   };
```

... to:

```
    key <HOME> {    [  Next         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Prior        ]   };
```

This will hardcode change those keys for *all* keyboards.

Comment: Finally something that worked! Spent too much time tweaking xformers